# Maya (Python) Search and Replace

Tags: python, maya

Need help to make search and replace work for my given options. I need to search and replace to work only on mesh, joints and locators only. This is what I have so far:

```
    def searchAndReplace(self):
    searchText = str(self.windowObj.myLookFor.text()) #My search text feild
    replaceText = str(self.windowObj.myRepFor.text()) #My replace text feild
    selection = cmds.ls(sl=True) #only selected items
    locators = cmds.listRelatives(cmds.ls(type= 'locator'), p=1)# Give me the list of locators 
    meshes = cmds.listRelatives(cmds.ls(type= 'mesh'), p=1) #Give me the list of all meshes
    joints = cmds.ls(type = 'joint')# Give me the list of my joints. 

    if len(selection) > 0:
        if self.windowObj.myRepAll.isChecked(): #Radial button to select everything in scene
            if locators.find(searchText) != -1:
                for loc in locators: #for all the locators in scene, add to loc
                    newName = locators.replace(searchText, replaceText) #search and replace 
                    cmds.rename(locators, newName) #add the new name.
```

But the error I have been getting is that I can't use ".find" on locators. The error I get is:

```
# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'
```

How can I solve this? Keep in mind I am a newbie to Python in Maya. Basically  I want the search and replace to work on all joints, locators and meshes I have in scene.

Answer (score 2):

This is what is throwing the error.

`if locators.find(searchText) != -1:`

The error message is pretty straight forward. You're trying to use `find` on a list, which doesn't work.

```
[].find
# Error: AttributeError: file <maya console> line 1: 'list' object has no attribute 'find' #
```

`find` is a string operation.

```
''.find
# Result: <built-in method find of str object at 0x1f43508> #
```

You need to use it when you loop through the objects' names, not on an array of them.

Comment: So which is the correct one? [].find or ' '.find is correct one? does find and replace only work via object module? Can you kind of explain a little more?

Comment: Did you even read my response or try it? I told you what the correct one is.